# Is Azure App Service now supporting GDI+ (System.Drawing)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, system.drawing, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I've been dealing with deploying an API that uses System.Drawing for a few weeks. I had it running in an Azure App Service and I used to get a "GDI+ generic exception". Now, out of nowhere started working. I looked for Microsoft announcements but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

GDI+ is still not supported now, please refer to [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions).

A [User voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/12864567-support-for-gdi) has already been submitted.

Comment: Is this still the case today? Got a project with `ImageResizer` in full .NET framework on a Azure App Service and it's working.That library uses system.drawing and GDI. Can't find any information about it that it does.

Comment: @Valderann, I just checked the doc, and no updates there. Can you please raise [github an issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues) with the details?