# Spire Presentation (Spire.Pres) launch an error in Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I use the library Spire.Presentation for edit a PowerPoint template.
In this case, append a memorystream in a shape (RectangleF).

```
IEmbedImage image = pSlide.Shapes.AppendEmbedImage(ShapeType.Rectangle, stream, item.Value);
```

pSlide is a reference for one page of PowerPoint slides.

item.value is the label on PowerPoint.

stream is my image (base64 to memory stream).

The project is run in a Microsoft Azure but at this line of code, generated this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
at System.Drawing.Image.CreateFromHandle(IntPtr handle)
at System.Drawing.Image.LoadFromStream(Stream stream, Boolean keepAlive)
at spr⁚.ᜁ(Stream A_0)
at Spire.Presentation.Collections.ShapeList.AppendEmbedImage(ShapeType shapeType, Stream stream, RectangleF rectangle)
```

Help me, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Azure App Service now supporting GDI+ (System.Drawing)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364192/is-azure-app-service-now-supporting-gdi-system-drawing)

Comment: No, because the Drawing library is insert into docker build.

Comment: OK.  Then you should edit your question stating what Azure services you're using.